# Angular UI Bootstrap Popover - Prevent default when triggering with click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a table with a number of rows, each can be selected, on the first column is an info button using bootstraps popover (UI Bootstrap Angular).

```
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign' popover-placement='right' popover='my notes to display'></span>
```

When I click on the item I want it not to select the item behind it.

I know this can be accomplished using e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation(), how do I implement this with bootsrap UI?

Thanks

Comment: You can use $event.preventDefault() in angular.

Comment: How would that work with UI Bootstrap, ui bootstrap seems to just work with attributes?

Comment: I said you can use it in angular views. So in your case I think you used angular so you can use it like ng-click="$event.preventDefault()". If not then tell your problem in detail.

Comment: almost right. but instead of preventDefault one should use here stopPropagation to avoid the event bubbling up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tell it to stop propagating events like so:

```
 <span ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign' popover-placement='right' popover='my notes to display'></span>
```

That should help.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2ot0FLCUQwj1gogBLON9?p=preview  clicking the i glyph triggers only its own event and not its parent event from the button.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick... because I'm rendering the code from inside a controller. some hacky stuff I didn't want to use compile with you example so i've done the following
onclick='(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })'

Comment: I had to use `$event.preventDefault();` for this to work in Angular6 in Chrome.